# fetch data from a database server to local application continuously

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, web-services

I have an application which collects some information from my customers by using an asp application in my website. This application writes information to database (sql server) which is in a remote server (web server). I want the information in database to be updated to my local PC in real time i.e. as soon as data is added to web server DB same should be downloaded to local server (offline server). To summarize I want to push notification of data changes from web server to local PC.

Comment: if both servers run sql server you can synchronize in database level

Comment: @Damith Can u tell me how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to accomplish this - which you choose depends on the constraints of your particular situation. 
The simplest is to just have your local application poll the server at regular intervals. This is crude but has the advantage that it will almost certainly work without modification to your router/firewall settings. Alternatively you could write code on the asp application to send a message to your local application only when a change occurs. This is a true push, but is likely to fail without port forwarding on your router; if you can configure the router, the code should be straightforward enough. 
Essentially this question is too vague to answer properly here - you will likely get some replies saying 'ok and which bit are you stuck with?', 'what have you tried?' etc